# Word is a Microsoft-developed application vs Word is an application developed by Microsoft

Tags: science

What is the best type of structure out of the following two possible structures for academic writing in scientific papers, one with a sentence in passive(A), and one with an adjective(B)?

A- Word is an application developed by Microsoft.

B- Word is a Microsoft-developed application.

This was just an example of the structures.

Thanks

Comment: [Duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/619998/2085).